# Best Way to add Commas to NgFor List

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I've seen some possible solutions. Solution 1 works fine but with solution 2 it just repeated my array 5 times.

```
test: string[]= ['apple', 'banna', 'mango', 'orange', 'pear'];
```

**HTML Solution 1:**

```
<p *ngFor="let x of test; let isLast=last">{{test}} {{isLast ? '' : ','}}</p>
```

[image]

**HTML Solution 2**

```
<p *ngFor="let x of test">{{test.join(",")}}</p>
```

also tried this and did not work:

```
// <p *ngFor="let x of test">{{x.join(",")}}</p>
```

[image]

Comment: With solution 2 you can simply exclude the `*ngFor` and you should get the desired output in a single `<p>`.  If you need multiple `<p>` tags then solution 1 is more appropriate

Comment: I tried that and it did not render on the screen, Not sure why

Comment: The solution 2 works without `ngFor`. See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dg6nwc?file=src/app/app.component.html).

Comment: you can do it with plain `js` `['apple', 'banna', 'mango', 'orange', 'pear'].join(", ")`

Comment: Solution 1 could be: `{{test + (isLast ? '' : ', ')}}`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There two way you can achieve this by using `join()` method of the array and using `*ngFor` like below

**app.component.html**

```
<h1>String Array Demo</h1>

<h2>Solution 1 - Using  <code> join() </code> method</h2>

<p>{{test.join(', ')}}</p>

<h2>Solution 2 Using <code> *ngFor </code> directive </h2>

<span *ngFor="let x of test; let i = index">
  {{x}} {{i === test.length -1 ? '' : ',&nbsp;' }}
</span>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  test: string[] = ['apple', 'banna', 'mango', 'orange', 'pear'];

}
```

**[Demo on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mriyze?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**

Hope this will help!

Comment: Well it would be an object from a service so I probably would need an Ng For. And Aslo what about spacing in your example

Comment: You can simply add `test.join(', ')` for spacing

Comment: check update stackblitz here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mriyze?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Ahh it looks like my issue was the way test was defined. Any clue why I can't define it like this:
`test: string[]= ['apple', 'banna', 'mango', 'orange', 'pear']; `
as oppossed to this: `test = ['apple', 'banna', 'mango', 'orange', 'pear']; `

Comment: that 's also the correct way of defining array. Even I updated stackblitz with the same and it's working!

Comment: Your right I think something else was breaking my code. so no way to do it with ngFor?

Comment: @Flash - You already provided a solution with `ngFor` (your solution 1).

Comment: I mean using solution two for an ngFor because in my solution the comma is not formatted correctly